# Accessing outer AND inner indexes inside nested arrays at the same time

Tags: dust.js, dust-helpers

I've got nested arrays such as:

```
"outer" : [
    {
        "inner": [
                    {},
                    {}
                 ]
    },
    {
        "inner": [
                    {},
                    {}
                 ]
    }
]
```

I neeed to generate an output like:

> outer[0].inner[0]
>
> outer[0].inner[1]
>
> outer[1].inner[0]
>
> outer[1].inner[1]

My problem is that once I'm inside the inner context, I do not know the outer index. `$idx` gives me the index of inner. Is there a way for me to access the outer index inside the inner context?

**Template example:**

```
{#outer}
{#inner}

outer[???].inner[{$idx}]

{/inner}
{/outer}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need to know the outer context, you could just pass the outer index($idx) as a parameter.

```
{#outer}
{#inner outIdx=$idx}
outer[{outIdx}].inner[{$idx}]
{/inner}
{/outer}
```